# MySQL connection failing from constructor

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, constructor

I'm trying to create a connection between my Java program and MySQL server (root , localhost:3306) and it works if I start the connection from my main with
`Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/", "root" ,"Password.");`

However, when I try to run this from a constructor which I call in my Main as
`bddFilmoteca newBDD = new bddFilmoteca();` it will always throw the error

> Communications link failure.  The last packet successfully received
> from the server was 265 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent
> successfully to the server was 259 milliseconds ago.

The constructor is:

```java
public class bddFilmoteca {
    // Attributes for the connection:
    private static String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"; 
    private static String BDD = "Filmoteca";
    private static String USER = "root";
    private static String PASSWORD = "Password.";
    private Connection con; //clase para crear una cadena de conexiÃ³n al servidor o a la BD concreta 
    
    public bddFilmoteca() {
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL + "?useSSL=true", USER ,PASSWORD);
            try {
                crearBDD();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            
        }
    }
```

Stacktrace is:

```
The last packet successfully received from the server was 265 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 259 milliseconds ago.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:202)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.negotiateSSLConnection(MysqlIO.java:4869)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1656)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1217)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2189)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2220)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:768)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:385)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:323)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at bddFilmoteca.<init>(bddFilmoteca.java:16)
    at mainFilmoteca.main(mainFilmoteca.java:16)
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL server and which version of MySQL Connector/J are you using? BTW: if it succeeds with `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"`, but fails with `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?useSSL=true"`, then that should be the first thing to check. The problem has nothing to do with being called in a constructor or elsewhere.

Comment: Try `URL + BDD + "?useSSL=true"`. You might use a separate db tool to check all.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to this.

It is not the object but the SSL=true string I added that makes the connection break. Without it it will give you a warning but allows you to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right. However would like to point out below things:

1. What is the name of database you are connecting to, your URL doesn't have name of any database. Instead of `private static String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"`, it should be `private static String URL = *"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somedatabasename"`
2. Ensure you have MySQL Connector/J on the classpath of project.
3. May change Connection con variable from private to static
4. Check if user id and password supplied is correctly typed. You mentioned password as "Password.". Does it really has dot at end?
5. Try after removing `?useSSL=true`, It should look like `con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER ,PASSWORD);`

Try these steps in order. I am attaching the code that I run and it worked:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.sql.*;

public class bddFilmoteca  {
    // Attributes for the connection:
    private static String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mdt"; 
    private static String BDD = "Filmoteca";
    private static String USER = "root";
    private static String PASSWORD = "root";
    private static Connection con; //clase para crear una cadena de conexiÃ³n al servidor o a la BD concreta 

    public bddFilmoteca() {
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,  USER ,PASSWORD);
            //+ "?useSSL=true",
           /* try {
                crearBDD();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }*/
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[]args) throws Exception
    {
         bddFilmoteca bdd= new  bddFilmoteca();
    Statement stmt =con.createStatement();
    String sql= "SELECT * FROM mdt.flats; ";
    ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next())
    {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
    }
    
    
    }
}
```